# Importing JavaScript Model using variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I would like to import My JavaScript Model from another file but I don't want to hard code part of that model. (I am using WebPack)

For example:
Module Location is `src/module/something.js`

In another javascript file, I want to import that using lazy load:

```
module = () => import('@/src/module/something');
```

The way I want to import it is:

```
let path_of_module = '@/src/module/something';
let module = () => import(path_of_module);
```

I am getting stuck in webpack building process.

How can I import a module using javascript variable which show that path of the module?

Comment: I am not especially sure about this but did you try using a path without the `@`. Might be related to that.

Comment: Yes I did that way, It is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is not allowed to have dependencies provided as expressions:

```sh
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

As I don't know your use case, I just guessing what might help you:
You could lazy load your modules to access them only when they are needed.

```js
const MyModule = () => Promise.resolve(import('../module/MyModule.js'));
```

In this case you would need to write some kind of switch to determine which module needs to load.

Comment: Actually I am trying to load component for  Vue.js which path is came from another json file. So, I must load component using variable that I get from json file. So, I am using base component that same way that you wrote in second snippet.